# Interchanging limits for an integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, measure-theory

Assume that $\mu$ and $(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are finite measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ such that for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu_n (A) = \mu(A). \tag{1}
$$
Now let $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable and bounded.

> Is it true that
> $$
> \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f \, d\mu_n = \int_{\Omega} f \, d\mu \tag{2}
> $$

Clearly, $(1)$ means that $(2)$ holds for all indicator functions $1_A$, $A\in \mathcal{F}$, and the linearity of the integral ensures that $(2)$ is true of all non-negative simple functions. If $f$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and non-negative, then there exists a sequence of increasing simple functions $(f_m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ converging to $f$. Assume that
$$
f_m = \sum_{i=1}^{k_m} a_{m, i} 1_{A_{m, i}}
$$
for some $k_m \in \mathbb{N}$. By the moonstone convergence theorem, we get
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f \, d\mu_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} \sum_{i=1}^{k_m} a_{m, i} 1_{A_{m, i}} \, d\mu_n.
$$
Now, is it possible to show that the limits can be interchanged? If so, the conclusion is straightforward.

Comment: :) The *moonstone convergence theorem*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed the claim is true for any *bounded* measurable $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

---

**Proof.** Let $s $ be any simple function such that $s \leq f$ everywhere. Then

\begin{align*}
\int s \, \mathrm{d}\mu
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int s \, \mathrm{d}\mu_n
\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu_n.
\end{align*}

Next, choose a sequence $(s_k)$ of simple functions such that $s_k \uparrow f$ everywhere. (It is clear that such a sequence exists.) Then $\int s_k \, \mathrm{d}\mu \uparrow \int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu$ by the monotone convergence theorem. So, we conclude

\begin{align*}
\int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu
= \lim_{k\to\infty} \int s_k \, \mathrm{d}\mu
\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu_n. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

Now applying the above inequality to $-f$ instead, we obtain

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu_n \leq \int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu. \tag{2} $$

Combining $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$, the desired conclusion follows.

---

**Addendum.** The proof that leads to $\text{(1)}$ also applies without modification to the case where $f$ is non-negative but not necessarily bounded. However, $\text{(2)}$ no longer need to hold for unbounded $f$. So, in this case, we cannot conclude that $\int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu_n$ tends to $\int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu$.

> **Counter-Example.** Let $\mu_n$ be the Borel measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ defined by
>
> $$ \mu_n(\mathrm{d}x) = n^{3/4} \mathbf{1}_{[n-\frac{1}{n}, n)}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$
>
> Since $\mu_n(\mathbb{R}) = n^{-1/4} \to 0$, we have $\mu_n(A) \to 0$ for any Borel subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, and hence the condition holds with $\mu \equiv 0$. On the other hand, if we set
>
> $$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \lfloor x \rfloor - x}}, $$
>
> then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \, \mathrm{d}\mu_n = 2n^{1/4} \to \infty$, whereas we clearly have $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \, \mathrm{d}\mu = 0$.

Comment: Remarkable counterexample, +1. However did you come up with that?

Comment: @FShrike, In this counter-example, $\mu_n$ represents some vanishing amount of mass distribution that drifts away towards infinity. I designed $f$ so that it amplifies the mass distribution represented by $\mu_n$.

Comment: Ah nice. I like the new simplified counterexample even better

Comment: $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f  \, d\mu = - \limsup_{ n \rightarrow \infty } \int_{\Omega} (-f) \, d\mu$. So don't you rather get $\limsup_{ n \rightarrow \infty } \int_{\Omega} (-f) \leq \int_{\Omega} ( - f ) \, d\mu$?

Comment: @Holden, "*... applying the above inequality to $-f$ instead*".

Comment: Isn't the equality above derived for non-negative $f$?

Comment: @Holden, I only assumed that $f$ is bounded and measurable, but otherwise arbitrary :)

Comment: If it is arbitrary, can you always find an increasing sequence of simple functions?

Comment: @Holden, Indeed. For example, you may choose $s_k = \lfloor 2^k f \rfloor / 2^k$. Since $f$ is bounded, $s_k$ takes only finitely many values and hence is a simple function. Also, it is easy to check that $s_k \uparrow f$. (Perhaps the easiest way to see why $s_k$ is increasing is to think about how it looks like under binary expansion.)

Comment: So instead of MCT you should apply DCT?

Comment: @Holden, DCT also works. I chose MCT because (1) MCT has a trivial generalization that applies to the sequence $g \leq f_1\leq f_2\leq f_3 \leq \ldots $ where $g$ is integrable but not necessarily non-negative (which is equivalent to the original MCT by considering the non-negative, increasing sequence $\tilde{f}_n = f_n - g$), and (2) MCT allows to show the inequality $\text{(1)}$ even when $f$ is assumed to be unbounded. If you do not care about the addendum I added, you can indeed use DCT instead.

Comment: @SangchulLee Is it possible to further say that $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \int f \, d \mu - \int f \, d \mu_n \right| = 0$ whenever $f$ is non-negative and integrable, but not necessarily bounded?

Comment: @Holden, Which measure with respect to which you are assuming $f$ is integrable? But anyway, you may first test if your statement remains valid in the case described in my answer.